# How to create a second bookmarks bar in firefox

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

> **Edit:** The selected answer provides all the wanted functionality (a separate bookmarks bar) besides the ability to position it.

I recently started using Firefox really like how they give you the customize button to setup your layout, but, I would like to take this a step further. Basically I want to keep my current bookmarks bar for all the sites I visit (google git hub etc.) but then have a second bookmarks bar for storing any bookmarklets I create up by all the other buttons in firefox:

[image: Toolbar]

Maybe there is a feature to duplicate widgets (or whatever you want to call them) but any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This would require you to write your own add-on.  There is no way, without an add-on, to do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin appears to do just that:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/more-bookmarks-toolbar/